# How to restrict the parameter of a method to a specific set of values?

Tags: c#

I would like to pass an argument to a method.

```
public void Foo(string range)
{
}
```

How can I restrict or limit the string passed to this method? Like only High/Medium/Low can be chosen when call `Foo`, not any other string?

Answer (score 6):

You can pass as [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum), instead of string.

```
public void Foo(Range range)
{
}


enum Range {
    High,
    Medium,
    Low
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. never used enum before. just tried your method above and worked great. I just have to add .toString() to convert the value to string format